# Using appendText property of Text Area returns error

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a textArea in my main application as:

```
<s:TextArea id="textAreaLog" visible="false" height="100%" width="100%"/>
```

I have another mxml file in which I access that textArea as:

```
import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
```

and then:

```
mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.textAreaLog.text = "Testing...\n;"
```

Above code works fine i.e. the string "Testing..." gets into the textAreaLog. But upon using **appendText** property of textArea as:

```
mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.textAreaLog.appendText = "Testing...\n;"
```

following error arises:

```
   Error #1037: Cannot assign to a method appendText on spark.components.TextArea.
```

Same error occurs if I use  instead of  where,

```
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
```

Any idea of how to resolve this problem. I am able to append text via following command which does not seem a good option or is it? Won't following line of code by inefficient if size of text in the Text Area increases considerably?

```
mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.textAreaLog.text += "Testing...\n;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.textAreaLog.appendText("your text");
```

More information about the `appendText()` method:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#appendText()

Good luck,
Rob